# Sort the order of an xml output using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, sorting, simplexml

I'm working with XML file that is being used as "database". in this example it holds information about books.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Then I want to display the book's price in my page, using simpleXML.
But my client asked for a "sort by" button. I couldn't find in Google and SO any way to sort the simpleXML output by let's say the object property "price".

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
$number = count($xml->book);        
        //Looping through the xml.
        for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {   ?>
            <div class="info">
                <span><?php echo((string) $xml->book[$i]->price); ?></span>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

As is it now, it just show me the book's price by the order they are written in the xml.
I thought maybe of using JS for this operation, but it seems very unlikely because this means I have to have all the books in one page. I even thought of using SQL and then the ORDER BY clause, but the problem is that this XML is dynamic and is changing all the time, which means I need to always watch for changes in the XML file and auto-update the SQL database, which I don't know how to do yet. What I'm really looking for is to alter the order of the XML using PHP, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible directly. You have to build an array from the xml, sort that array, and then build back the xml. Create 2 arrays, one to keep the xml segments, where the index is the book_id and the value is the segment. The second only with the book id as a key and as values the field that you want to sort by using [asort](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php). Sort the second array and rebuild the xml.

== UPDATE ==

Maybe there is a possibility to sort an xml using xPath an XSL, here you have a [link](http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/1560361/How-to-use-XPath-and-Sorting-in-XML.htm).

Comment: I think xpath is the better solution here, thank you.